# Service not running when application exits

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

**MyService:**
 public class MyService extends Service{

```
  public void onStartCommand(...){
   //....
   return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
       Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
       startService(intent);
  }
}
```

I have created a service as coded above. It is working proper in most of the devices. But when I tested in asus zenfone 2, if the user close the application, the service also stops. I have googled for this issue, and din't find similar device specific issue. What could be the reason for behaving like this in particular device ? And how do I resolve this,thanks!

Comment: Services will be killed by the system if they are not in the `foreground` state. This will depend on lots of factors (memory constraints, cpu, other apps, battery, etc.). Check out doc about foreground services at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: 'Services will be killed by the system if they are not in the foreground state' means services will be killed when app goes background ? then what is the usage of Service ?, Service killed because of so many reasons, but it will restart automatically if we wants.

Comment: Yes, they are more likely to be killed if the app is no longer in the foreground state. Background services are used to do background tasks such as syncs. From the docs: `A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory.`

Comment: then how you are getting facebook updates and whatsapp message ? they all running background services, isn't it ?

Comment: What do you mean by **user exits the application**. What do you do when the use **exits**? Also, what do you mean by **the Service also closes**. Please be specific.

Comment: Service stops when the user comes out from the app

Comment: They certainly uses mechanisms like GoogleCloudMessaging, SyncAdapters, AlarmManager, etc. that are only awake when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got resolved the issue, the problem was not with the Service or Coding, there is an application pre-installed in asus zefone called auto-start manager, that disables the service when app goes in background, so user has to enable background running facility for the specific application.

Comment: What does it mean by  enable background running facility for the specific application

Comment: in that application all the apps in the phone will be listed. you will have to manually enable the background service permission for the app that you want.. which is similar to ios 9+ permission management .concept

Comment: how to manually enable  background service permission? where can i find it ?

Comment: it is asus zen phone feature. not every phones.

Comment: Pls have a look on this thread and help me out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610424/android-service-start-sticky-not-working-in-micromax-q382-phone-android-5-1-lol?noredirect=1#comment70422270_41610424